Raspberry from nodered currently is not reading from GPIO
I am having a few problems on my solution from Nodered to Raspberry pi.
The target should be to read an input from a Raspberry Pi, read it in Nodered make a decision, and then lights up an output, we can say that it's the classic blinking led problem with the GPIO nodes on Nodered.
The led actually blinking if i send him a timestamp, but if i use a switch on the GPIO n° 11 - IN1 i don't see any answer from the raspberry.
I have installed all the python modules, i have installed npm onoff module, but it's not working.
May you help me on this?
Thank you in advice, let me know if you need any part of the JSON file or information about my raspberry pi2

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

from Nodered to Raspberry pi ... where is Node-RED running?

@jsotola On the Raspberry.

are you saying that you are using two Raspberrys?

No. Nodered is installed on my raspberry and through VNC i am watching the screen. I connected a switch on I1 and a lamp on O1. If i send a msg.payload from nodered to the lamp, through the Node Raspberry GPIO the lamp lights. If i tilt the switch, i am seeing that the led turn on the raspberry but on nodered i don't see the "true" on the input status.
